# Criteria for the difference of two matrices to be positive semidefinite when the eigenvectors are known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a rank 1 positive semidefinite matrix and $B$ a Hermitian matrix. Suppose I know the eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$ and that $A-B$ is also positive semidefinite.

Apart from Weyl's inequality is there anything that can be deduced about the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking for, since you say you know that eigenvalues of $B$, and that you want to know about the eigenvalues of $B$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've not been clear enough. I know the _eigenvectors_ of $B$ not the eigenvalues. I also know the matrix A since it's rank 1 and I know the eigenvector.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should expect to be able to say very little about the eigenvalues of $B$: any negative definite $B$ will satisfy your conditions, which means that any $n$-tuple of negative numbers can appear as eigenvalues of $B$.

Some more information could be gathered from specific knowledge of the eigenvectors; for example, if $A$ and $B$ share an eigenvector, that gives you a condition on an eigenvalue of $B$.